# Regular expression for twitter username

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a javascript regular expression to match twitter usernames.

The username is entered by the user while signing up, so I don't want to distract them with too many error notifications. Because of that, I need the expression to match valid usernames regardles if they have the @ before the username or not.

Twitter usernames can contain latin characters, underscores and numbers, and the only limitation is the can be up to 15 characters long. ( but I need the regex to match 16 characters as well, in case someone enters the @ before the username ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regex for Twitter username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304632/regex-for-twitter-username)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This should do:
`^@?(\w){1,15}$`

Comment: even though it would work just find for the OP, just wanted to make a general comment for those who don't know 'regex'. This test will only match if the username being checked is the only set of characters present in a given line of text or a string, depending on the version of 'regex' engine, which is why it's enclosed between ^ and $, but this test would fail if there are any other characters present, including white space characters, in the same line or string... just wanted to state the fact, so someone won't try to use this for something like a full text search. :)

Comment: What's the role of `?` here?

Comment: It's a quantifier meaning the preceding class/group/character is to be matched 0 or 1 time

Comment: don't forget that a twitter handle doesn't allow the words "admin" or "twitter" anywhere in the name/handle

Comment: If you put the repeater outside of the capture group, it will only capture the last possible match of `\w`. So for example, `@zac` would capture the group `c`. To make it capture the whole handle, put the repeater inside the parenthesis as in `^@?(\w{1,15})$`.

Comment: @asenovm I thought a Twitter Username had to have an @ at the beginning. The ? makes the @ optional...

Answer (score 46):

This is the best solution I found yet to replace multiple occurrences of a twitter username.

The regex doing the trick is `/(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})\b/`. I am catching what stand behind the @ character so I can replace the username correctly. And I am using global match flag (g) so it will replace all occurrences. 
[asenovm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588264/asenovm) answer is simple, but will not work in most user input contexts, as [techexpert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559669/techexpert) is explaining in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650007/regular-expression-for-twitter-username?lq=1#comment12819310_8650024).

```js
var output,
    text    = "@RayFranco is answering to @AnPel, this is a real '@username83' but this is an@email.com, and this is a @probablyfaketwitterusername",
    regex   = /(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})\b/g,
    replace = '$1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2">@$2</a>';

output = text.replace( regex, replace );

console.log ( output );
```

This is giving me what I expected *(tested with node v0.9.1)* :

> [@RayFranco](http://twitter.com/RayFranco) is answering to [@AnPel](http://twitter.com/AnPel), this is a real '[@username83](http://twitter.com/username83)' but this is an@email.com, and this is a @probablyfaketwitterusername

This is based on [Twitter "specs" for username](https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299-why-can-t-i-register-certain-usernames#error) :

> *Your username cannot be longer than 15 characters. Your real name can be longer (20 characters), but usernames are kept shorter for the sake of ease. A username can only contain alphanumeric characters (letters A-Z, numbers 0-9) with the exception of underscores, as noted above. Check to make sure your desired username doesn't contain any symbols, dashes, or spaces.*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

A short an easy way to do it:

```
function validTwitteUser(sn) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}$/.test(sn);
}
```

Comment: Thats perfect... In case if someone doesn't want their regex to have number in the begining they can modify the above regex as /^[a-zA-Z_]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,14}$/

Answer (score 6):

@[a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,15}

You can use above regular expression to sort of the twitter usernames from a mixed set of data

Answer (score 3):

Another one that does the work is:

`/(?<!\w)@[\w+]{1,15}\b/`

- The first part `(?<!\w)@` matches `@` if there is no character value before it.
  That can be used as a filter for potential email addresses that have the format `text@mail.com`. Since there is text before `@` the email address is not matched.
- The second part `[\w+]{1,15}\b` matches a string of word characters namely a-z,A-Z,0-9,_ that are accepted in a twitter username. The word boundary anchor`\b` matches the space between a word character and a non word character. Non word characters are not accepted in the twitter username and are therefore excluded from the match because of `\b`.

Last but not least I provide a picture where I tested the proposed regex on the text provided in the second most voted answer by rayfranco to check for matches.

screenshot,
[image: screenshot image]

Comment: I believe there is a typo, an extra unnecessary space after `\b`?

Comment: thank you @mjsarfatt you are correct. 
I meant to write `/(?<!\w)@[\w+]{1,15}\b/`

Answer (score 2):

This could be help for a `Full Match` :

```
^@(?=.*\w)[\w]{1,15}$
```

Testing: `@John_Doe2000`

Results:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-13    @John_Doe2000
```

Try [Here](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

To exclude **"non-latin"** characters, you have to use: `^@?([a-zA-Z0-9_]){1,15}$`. Because, `\w` accepts "any word characters". And non-latin characters qualifies this condition. So, it matches even `üö` like Turkish characters as well.

Comment: that's not true. \w matches exactly [a-zA-Z0-9_] and nothing else.

Comment: Before commenting something, please at least test it and make sure that it's true. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wBPEQ/

Comment: I don't see what this proves. All I'm saying is that \w is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9_] and \w does NOT match letters other from those in the English alphabet.

Comment: Seems regular expression implementation differs from platforms to platforms. It works that way on .NET but fails on browsers.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @asenovm's answer, this will select twitter handles that are not in strings by themselves, and will also select the colon that is present in a retweet:

```
@(\w){1,15}(:|)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be more than you need but I found this in another post "[regex how to replace twitter links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020739/regex-how-to-replace-twitter-links)". Wraps @usernames, #hashtags and urls. Working well for me.

```
function processTweetLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi;
    text = text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
    exp = /(^|\s)#(\w+)/g;
    text = text.replace(exp, "$1<a href='https://twitter.com/hashtag/$2?src=hash' target='_blank'>#$2</a>");
    exp = /(^|\s)@(\w+)/g;
    text = text.replace(exp, "$1<a href='http://www.twitter.com/$2' target='_blank'>@$2</a>");
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct regex is this `/^@(\w){1,15}/g` without the ? on @(at)