# Search string for Twitter handle(s) in Swift using RegEx

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I've been doing some work on a simple messaging system that looks for Twitter handles in text and takes actions when there's a hit.

With JavaScript, it's easy ... from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650007/regular-expression-for-twitter-username) the `/(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})\b/g` RegEx works great at identifying valid Twitter handles.

With Swift, I'm hitting a wall. I can't even manage to create the regex mentioned above. When I try:

```
var = "/(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})\b/g"
```

I get an `Invalid escape sequence in literal` error.

If I double the backslashes on the `w`'s and `b` (ex: `/(^|[^@\\w])@(\\w{1,15})\\b/g`, then the error goes away, but, obviously, that changes the regex.

I've looked at [this great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial) by Ray Wenderlich, but I still don't understand what I need to do to move past the error I'm getting. Both `\w` and `\b` appear to be valid operators.

Can someone sort me out?

Comment: `\\w` *is* the correct way to write `\w` (match a word character) in a Swift string, because the backslash has to be escaped. Did you check if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot not use the `/` delimiters at both ends as in JavaScript, remove them, and also use double-escapes:

```
var = "(^|[^@\\w])@(\\w{1,15})\\b"
```