# how do I extract all links from twitter feed?

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter

I use "jquery-lifestream (https://github.com/christianv/jquery-lifestream/)" to get social feed from FB and twitter.
It works fine.

But I can't have all links clickable.

- FB links are OK
- twitter hashtags links are OK
- twitter @ links are OK

But not the links for the pictures...
Here's the code :

```
    var linkify = function( tweet ) {

  var link = function( t ) {

    //Add link to all http:// links within tweets
    return t.replace(
      /((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g,
      function( m ) {
        return '<a href="' + m + '" target="_blank">' +
          ( ( m.length > 25 ) ? m.substr( 0, 24 ) + '...' : m ) +
          '</a>';
      }
    );
  },
  at = function( t ) {
    return t.replace(
      /(^|[^\w]+)\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})/g,
      function( m, m1, m2 ) {
        return m1 + '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + m2 + '" target="_blank">@' +
          m2 + '</a>';
      }
    );
  },

  pc = function( t ) {
    return t.replace(
      /* WHAT DO I PUT HERE ? */
      function( m ) {
        return '<a href="http://pic.twitter.com/' + m + '" target="_blank">' + m + '</a>';
      }
    );
  },

  hash = function( t ) {
    return t.replace(

    /\B#([_a-z0-9ÅåÄäÖöØøÆæÉéÈèÜüÊêÛûÎî_]+)/ig, function(reply) {
    return '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q='+encodeURI(reply.substring(1))+'" target="_blank">'+reply.charAt(0)+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    }

    );
  };
  return hash(pc(at(link(tweet))));

}
```

I tried several regexp, none of them doing the job, as I'm no js expert...

Question have been asked here, but answers didn't help for me => ie: [regex how to replace twitter links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020739/regex-how-to-replace-twitter-links))
Also found this script (https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js/blob/master/twitter-text.js) but I can't run it properly, so I don't know if it works for me..

How do I get links for the pictures without messing the whole thing up ?
Thanks

[EDIT] thanks to regex101 too (and their online tester), as I finally got to this final solution :)

```
    return t.replace(
        /((pic.twitter.com)\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*?$)/i,
      function( m, m1, m2 ) {
        return '<a href="http://' + m + '" target="_blank">' + m + '</a>';
      }
    );
```

Thanks

Comment: can you put a sample for the feed?

Comment: You mean, the json returned by the twitter API ?
As I'm using someonelse's script, I assumed it comes like this : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets and that's where I looked for the answer before.
Does it help ?

Comment: So far, I managed to write this part, and test it here http://regex101.com/#javascript ->
            return t.replace(
            /((pic.twitter.com)\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*?$)/i,
          function( m ) {
            return '<a href="http://pic.twitter.com"' + m + '" target="_blank">' + m + '</a>';
          }
        );

Capturing group seems to be fine, but I have a link without the slash trailing 10-digits...